# #TYPE...Format.FormatStartData when in csv output from Export-CSV

Tags: powershell

Code

```
$time =[DateTime]::Now.AddHours(-15)
$session = Get-XAServer -WorkerGroupName test |Get-XASession |Where-Object {$_.State -eq "disconnected"-and $_.Logontime -lt $time}|Select Accountname,connecttime,disconnecttime,ServerName,Logontime |export-csv test.csv
```

Output CSV Error:

```
#TYPE Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData
ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd
033ecb2bc07a4d43b5ef94ed5a35d280
9e210fe47d09416682b841769c78b8a3
27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c
```

Also, i am getting screen out like this

```
AccountName    : user1
ConnectTime    : 12/8/2014 11:24:17 PM
DisconnectTime : 12/9/2014 7:00:26 AM
ServerName     : Test
LogOnTime      : 12/8/2014 11:24:41 PM
```

But want my output like the below format:

```
AccountName                   ConnectTime                   DisconnectTime
-----------                   -----------                   --------------
```

Comment: What happens when you remove `$session = ` from the beginning of that line. You are outputing and assigning that output to a variable at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that your issues are coming from assigning output to both a variable and to output for `Export-CSV`. I should think your csv would look better if you remove the assignment from the beginning of that line.

```
Get-XAServer -WorkerGroupName test |
    Get-XASession |
    Where-Object {$_.State -eq "disconnected" -and $_.Logontime -lt $time}|
    Select Accountname,connecttime,disconnecttime,ServerName,Logontime |
    export-csv test.csv
```

If you really need the information in a variable you could split that up into 2 lines. Tee-Object would also do this.

```
$session = Get-XAServer -WorkerGroupName test |
    Get-XASession |
    Where-Object {$_.State -eq "disconnected" -and $_.Logontime -lt $time}|
    Select Accountname,connecttime,disconnecttime,ServerName,Logontime 
$session | export-csv test.csv
```

You might have other syntactical issues but I think this is a start. I don't have access to those cmdlets and I am unable to recreate this behavior with others. Does this on its own give you the proper output you are looking for?

```
Get-XAServer -WorkerGroupName test |
        Get-XASession |
        Where-Object {$_.State -eq "disconnected" -and $_.Logontime -lt $time}|
        Select Accountname,connecttime,disconnecttime,ServerName,Logontime
```